# What type of address is this?

Tags: tcp

As the title says I'm curious as to the type of address this is as its clearly not IPv4 or v6, yet it is using TCP.

[image]

Comment: What is the OS, and what command did you run to get this?

Comment: It's the hostname of the connecting device minus the domain. They just named it with its IP address in that dash-delimited format.

Comment: thanks boomi that hit the nail on the head. now i dont know if i've installed something from akamai or if our company has some cloud storage with them.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking at a Windows `netstat` output, netstat without the `-n` option resolves each IP address via reverse DNS (PTR record) and displays the result.

In your case that's simply the reverse DNS name of a connected HTTPS server. Note that it's not a valid FQDN as that would require including the domain.

Comment: Yes output from "netstat /b", it'd be nice to see the output of "netstat /b /n" but now the connection is gone and I dont know what was making it. boomis comment on the dash delimited ip address lead me to what I was looking for